# How to relate non-harmonic oscillation to harmonic oscillation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the follwoing equation
$$\partial_t^2\phi(t)+\lambda\phi^3(t)=0. \tag{1}$$
This equation describes an oscillator in a potential $V(\phi)=\phi^4/4$. And we know that the solution is the elliptic consine function:
$$\phi(t)=\phi_0{\rm cn}[\sqrt{\lambda}\phi_0t,1/\sqrt{2}],$$
where $\phi_0$ is an integration constant.

Since the elliptic cosine function is also a periodic function, I would assume that it is possible to  relate it to the cosine function by a rescalling of the time. So is it possible to transform Eq. (1) to the equation of motion for a harmonic oscillator with a rescalling of time $t\rightarrow \tau=f(t)$,
$$(\partial_\tau^2+\omega^2)\phi=0$$
with some frequency $\omega$
?

Answer (score 3):

The function you're looking for is actually the Jacobi amplitude function. Let
$$\operatorname{Eli}_1(\phi;k)=\int_0^\phi\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1-(k\sin t)^2}}$$
Be an elliptic integral of the first kind. Define the inverse with respect to the first argument
$$\operatorname{am}(u;k):=\operatorname{Eli}_1^{-1}(u;k)$$
It satisfies
$$\operatorname{cn}(u;k)=\cos(\operatorname{am}(u;k))$$
So in your case a change of variable
$$\tau=\operatorname{am}(\sqrt{\lambda}\phi_0~t;1/\sqrt{2})$$
Will do the trick. Letting $\sqrt{\lambda}=\phi_0=1$ below is a plot of the two:
[image]

As you can see they are identical.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But I was actually looking for something a bit different. I was wondering how to transform equation (1) to a harmonic equation. In principle, one should not assume an known answer for the equation in this procedure.

Comment: @WeinEld I'm not sure what you mean? The immediate consequence of my work above is that the change of variable $\tau=\operatorname{am}(\sqrt{\lambda}\phi_0~t;1/\sqrt{2})$ will yield the harmonic oscillator equation.